# Android Passing data between Interactors MVP

Tags: android, mvp

Good day developers, I'm having trouble figuring out how and what should I do correctly so that I won't violate the MVP principle so I have the following situation.

A view that shows List of object, when a particular object is clicked my `ViewHolder` tells the `Presenter` about the click event.

What I want is ,when the object is clicked I want to start a new `Activity` that will display that particular object that was clicked.

**Option 1.**

Pass the id of the clicked object to `Interactor`(How should I do it I have no idea) of newly started activity, where a new api call will be called and will return a result based on given id.

**Option 2.**

On the other hand if I don't want to make a new api call and would like to simply pass the `Object` to the `Iterator` of new activity.

**(What is better for performance to make a new api call or pass the object around?)**

If any of my options seems somehow okay, then how should I implement them correctly?

If they are not then what is a alternative way of doing it?

Comment: Depending on the object's complexity, you could pass it through Intent extra. Another way is to pass the id and get again the object, but a cached version, of course. You don't need (and you mustn't) to make 2 requests to your api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use the new Blueprints which include Viewmodels in the form of LiveData, and there are specific mechanisms in the viewmodel for sharing the model between views. Basically the model is held with the key being a view id, but if you have a view and then a number of fragments, they can all access it.

Technically you have control over the key:

`final UserModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserModel.class);`

What I like about this is it solves the scoping problem that has haunted MVC: either use Singletons or pass data around all over the place.